# How long should a thread sleep for to give other threads enough time to get from a queue?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from threading import get_ident
from queue import *

_urls = Queue()

class URLParser(Thread):

    def run(self):
        global _urls
        while _urls.qsize() > 0:
            url = archive_urls.get()
            _urls.task_done()
            # .... Omitted some code here where I do some work on the url, for brevity
            print(str(get_ident()) + ' consumed:' + url + ' qsize:' + str(_urls.qsize()))
            sleep(0.002)
```

How long should my thread sleep so that other threads can consume from the queue ? I do not want to specify a number too large, as then I may be wasting time, or too small and miss out on the benefit of all the threads consuming...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sleeping in your worker thread is unnecessary. It's done sometimes in examples to visualize the flow of a multi-threaded program, but there's no reason you should do it in production code.

When one thread has finished a task, it may as well pick up the next task immediately. It's not going to make your program faster that another thread takes the task instead. The only thing you would achieve is that the worker threads sit idle every now and then.